# is heat transfer through conduction of metal faster than convection of air?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

Is heat transfer through metal by conduction faster than heat transfer of heated metal to surrounding by convection ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, as long as the hot metal is pressed into firm contact with the object being heated. Even a small air-filled gap will greatly reduce heat transfer, and as the gap width is increased, the heat transfer mechanism switches over from conduction to convection.